# PDF Format Word spacing syntax

Tags: pdf

How do I format the PDF string so it will render the text with reduced word spacing?

My font size is 12, but I don't know how to add additional parameters to adjust the word spacing:

```
BT /F1 12 Tf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read `PDF Reference 1.7`. Section `5.2 Text State Parameters and Operators`, page 399.

`Tw` - Word spacing. Default value is 0.

[image]

Comment: I stand corrected, and you are right… I deleted my answer (or attempted to do so).